# The thread created by pthread_create the same with the kernel thread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I use the command below to view the maximum number of threads my system allows:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

And the number is 772432.

However, I use the code below to create 1 million threads. And it works.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long long thread_nr = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex_;

void* inc_thread_nr(void* arg) {
    /* int arr[1024][1024]; */
    (void*)arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    thread_nr ++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int err;
    int cnt = 0;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);

    while (cnt < 1000000) {
        pthread_t pid;
        err = pthread_create(&pid, NULL, (void*)inc_thread_nr, NULL);
        if (err != 0) {
            break;
        }
        pthread_join(pid, NULL);
        cnt++;
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);
    printf("Maximum number of threads per process is = %d\n", thread_nr);
}
```

The output is :

```
Maximum number of threads per process is = 1000000
```

which is larger than the maximum number of threads. What is the reason for this? And is the thread create by `pthread_create` the same with the kernel thread?

My OS is Fedora 16, with 12 cores, 48G RAM.

Comment: That might be because you are only running one thread at a time... You create it, then you immediately wait for it to end.

Comment: Oh, I see. I am so silly. Thanks, @JoachimPileborg and is there any difference between the thread created by pthread_create and the kernel thread?

Comment: `pthread_create` creates a thread. Kernel takes care of it. That's it.

Comment: In Linux there is really no difference between threads and processes, they both use the same internal structures. So I don't think there's any difference between a "kernel" thread and a userland (e.g. POSIX) thread.

Comment: Thanks,  @iccthedral  So, the relationship between the threads created by pthread_create and the kernel threads is a one-to-one mapping?

Comment: Thanks, @JoachimPileborg I guess the different between threads and processes in Linux is that threads created by the same process share the same address space while processes have their own.

Comment: Threads and processes are actually created using the same (Linux-specific) system call: [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone), the difference is the flags used. Threads, for example, use the flag `CLONE_VM` to tell the kernel that the new "process" should share the same virtual memory as the parent.

Comment: You are correct, @JoachimPileborg Thanks. And could you help me solve this proble? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387828/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-threads-that-pthread-create-can-create