# What is the maximum number of threads that pthread_create can create?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The thread create by pthread_create the same with the kernel thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387436/the-thread-create-by-pthread-create-the-same-with-the-kernel-thread)

I use the code below to test the maximum number of threads that the pthread_create function can create.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static unsigned long long thread_nr = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex_;

void* inc_thread_nr(void* arg) {
    (void*)arg;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    thread_nr ++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);

    /* printf("thread_nr = %d\n", thread_nr); */

    sleep(300000);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int err;
    int cnt = 0;

    pthread_t pid[1000000];

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);

    while (cnt < 1000000) {

        err = pthread_create(&pid[cnt], NULL, (void*)inc_thread_nr, NULL);
        if (err != 0) {
            break;
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    pthread_join(pid[cnt], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);
    printf("Maximum number of threads per process is = %d\n", thread_nr);
}
```

And the output is :

```
Maximum number of threads per process is = 825
```

Is that the maximum number of threads that the pthread_create function can create?

Besides, I use the command below to view the maximum number of threads my system allows:

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

And the number is 772432.

Why is the output of my program not equal to the value of `threads-max` ?

My OS is Fodaro 16, with 12 cores, 48G RAM.

Comment: The `pthread_create()` function can only create one thread. You may call it multiple times -- apparently 825 without error. This may vary though with system loading, process changes, and other variables changing.

Comment: @iccthedral They are not duplicates. They focus on different aspects and with different questions.

Comment: Please could you tell me why you need so many threads?

Comment: please tell us what `errno` you have observed.

Comment: last line should be `printf("Maximum number of threads per process is = %d\n", cnt);`

Comment: In the original "dup" question, they ask why their program can create unlimited threads.  That was answered in the comments as a mistake in the program.  In this question, they fixed the initial bug and ask why they can only create 825 threads.  Same asker, similar code, different question.  *Not a duplicate.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The default size for the per-thread stack is artificially imposing the limit in your test.  While the default stack given to the process (the initial thread) grows dynamically as needed, the stacks for the other threads are fixed in size.  The default size is usually extremely large, something like two megabytes, to make sure the per-thread stack is large enough for even the pathological cases (deep recursion and so on).

In most cases, thread workers need very little stack.  I've found that on all architectures I've used, 64k (65536 bytes) per-thread stack is sufficient, as long as I don't use deeply recursive algorithms or large local variables (structures or arrays).

To explicitly specify a per-thread stack size, modify your `main()` to something like the following:

```
#define MAXTHREADS 1000000
#define THREADSTACK  65536

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t       pid[MAXTHREADS];
    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    int  err, i;
    int  cnt = 0;

    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREADSTACK);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);

    for (cnt = 0; cnt < MAXTHREADS; cnt++) {

        err = pthread_create(&pid[cnt], &attrs, (void*)inc_thread_nr, NULL);
        if (err != 0)
            break;
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        pthread_join(pid[i], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);

    printf("Maximum number of threads per process is %d (%d)\n", cnt, thread_nr);
}
```

Note that `attrs` is not consumed by the `pthread_create()` call. Think of the thread attributes more like a template on how `pthread_create()` should create the threads; *they are not attributes given to the thread*.  This trips up many aspiring pthreads programmers, so it's one of those things you'd better get right from the get go.

As to the stack size itself, it must be at least `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN` (16384 in Linux, I believe) and divisible by `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`. Since page size is a power of two on all architectures, using a large enough power of two should always work.

Also, I added a fix in there, too. You only try to join a nonexistent thread (the one that the loop tried to create, but failed), but you need to join all of them (to make sure they're all done their job).

Further recommended fixes:

Instead of using a sleep, use a condition variable. Have each thread wait (`pthread_cond_wait()`) on the condition variable (while holding the mutex), then release the mutex and exit. That way your main function only needs to broadcast (`pthread_cond_broadcast()`) on the condition variable to tell all threads they can now exit, then it can join each one, and you can be sure that that number of threads were really concurrently running. As your code stands now, some threads may have enough time to wake up from the sleep and exit.

Comment: Note that `<limits.h>` should define `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`, which is the minimum stack size the architecture needs for a thread function. So, you could use e.g. `#define THREADSTACK (PTHREAD_STACK_MIN + 32768)`, although for portability, you should round that up to a multiple of `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`.

Comment: Congratulations on your great answer ! I have a question about your use of a condition variable: won't a thread finish too early that way ? And so won't many threads be alive at the same time ?

Answer (score 6):

In theory, there's no limit on the number of threads a process can have. But the practical restriction could come from the fact that all threads share the resources.

It means at some point, a process can't create more than a certain number of processes due to lack resources to share with such stack space, for example.

Comment: Running out of memory due to to many stacks is very likely. On a 32-bit machine the default stack size of 2M, so with 825 threads thats over 1.5 gigs of memory. 64-bit systems uses 8M for stack, so it's over 6.5 gig.

Comment: @Joachim: so the 32 bit version has probably exhausted the address space thereabouts, and can't assign more. The 64 bit version might keep on trucking, 6.5GB of address space is small, so there might be more to this observed limit than just the sum of stacks.

Comment: In theory, there **is** a limit:`2^(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(pthread_t)`...

Comment: @SteveJessop: Thread stacks consume commit charge too, not just virtual address space. 6.5 GB sounds like a likely possible value for `(swap + ram/2)`, the default commit charge limit on Linux. By default Linux does not do strict commit accounting, but it does try to prevent drastic overcommit.

Comment: @R..: hmm, the questioner claims to have 48GB RAM.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Must be some other kind of limit.

Answer (score 3):

According to `pthread_create(3)` man page, there is another limit :

```
RLIMIT_NPROC soft resource limit (set via setrlimit(2)), which limits the number 
of process  for  a real user ID.
```

Try to find the value of this limit with `getrlimit(2)`. If the value still does not match the number you measured (825), try to change this limit with `setrlimit(2)` to verify if it affects your measurements.

**EDIT:** In fact the RLIMIT_NPROC limit value is the same that the one obtained with the shell command `ulimit -u` (that prints / set the max user processes).