# Pthreads pool, keeping 1000 opened threads, pthread_create() returns 11

Tags: c++, multithreading

Need some help with PTHREADS. I want to keep over 1000 threads opened at any time, something like a thread pool. Here is the code :

```
/*
gcc -o test2 test2.cpp -static -lpthread -lstdc++
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>

int NUM_THREADS = 2000;
int MAX_THREADS = 100;
int THREADSTACK = 65536;

struct thread_struct{
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
};

pthread_mutex_t mutex_;
static unsigned int thread_count = 0;

string exec(const char* cmd)
{
    int DEBUG=0;

    char buffer[5000];
    string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe && DEBUG) throw runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    try 
    {
        while (!feof(pipe)) 
        {
            if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            {
                result += buffer;
            }

        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }

    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}


void *thread_test(void *arguments)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    thread_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);

    // long tid;
    // tid = (long)threadid;

    struct thread_struct *args = (thread_struct*)arguments;

    /*
    printf("ARG1=%d\n",args->arg1);
    printf("ARG2=%d\n",args->arg2);
    */

    int thread_id = (int) args->arg1;

    /*
    int random_sleep;
    random_sleep = rand() % 10 + 1;
    printf ("RAND=[%d]\n", random_sleep);
    sleep(random_sleep);
    */

    int random_sleep;
    random_sleep = rand() % 10 + 5;
    // printf ("RAND=[%d]\n", random_sleep);

    char command[100];
    memset(command,0,sizeof(command));
    sprintf(command,"sleep %d",random_sleep);
    exec(command);


    random_sleep = rand() % 100000 + 500000;

    usleep(random_sleep);

    // simulation of a work between 5 and 10 seconds
    // sleep(random_sleep);

    // printf("#%d -> sleep=%d total_threads=%u\n",thread_id,random_sleep,thread_count);


    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    thread_count--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    // pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    int i;

    usleep(10000);

    srand ((unsigned)time(NULL));
    unsigned int thread_count_now = 0;


    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREADSTACK);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);

    for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        create_thread:
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
        thread_count_now = thread_count;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);

        // printf("thread_count in for = [%d]\n",thread_count_now);


        if(thread_count_now < MAX_THREADS)
        {
            printf("CREATE thread [%d]\n",i);

            struct thread_struct struct1;
            struct1.arg1 = i;
            struct1.arg2 = 999;

            pthread_t temp_thread;


            rc = pthread_create(&temp_thread, NULL, &thread_test, (void *)&struct1);
            if (rc)
            {
                printf("Unable to create thread %d\n",rc);

                sleep(1);
                pthread_detach(temp_thread);
                goto create_thread;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            printf("Thread POOL full %d of %d\n",thread_count_now,MAX_THREADS);

            sleep(1);
            goto create_thread;
        }


    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);

    // pthread_attr_destroy(&attrs);

    printf("Proccess completed!\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 1;
}
```

After spawning 300 threads it begins to give

errors, return code from pthread_create() is 11, and after that keeps executing them one by one.

What im i doing wrong?

Comment: In general, spawning hundreds of threads is a bad idea, as thread performance tends not to scale up well.  You might want to reconsider the design of your program in favor of using dozens, rather than hundreds of threads.  Ideally the number of threads in your program would be equal to the number of cores on the machine.

Comment: why you say this? i have programs that i run using `fork()` and it helps me a lot, i even had a performance on 1500 forks at all time

Comment: It would have worked more efficiently with fewer threads.  Each thread has to allocate space for its own separate stack, which uses up memory.  Furthermore, every time a CPU has to switch from one thread to another, it requires a context switch, which eats up CPU cycles.  Finally, if you are using processes instead of threads (as implied by your mention of using fork() rather than pthread_create()), then each process also requires its own process space, which eats up a lot of extra memory.  You can use lots of threads/processes (until you hit the system's limits, anyway) but it's inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [website](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html), error code 11 corresponds to EAGAIN which means according to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

- Insufficient resources to create another thread.
- A system-imposed limit on the number of threads was encountered.

Hence to solve your problem either create less threads or wait for running ones to finish before creating new ones.

You can also change default thread stack size see [pthread_attr_setstacksize](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you look closely i actually used `pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREADSTACK);` , is it used correctly?

Comment: Yes as long as you don't put a `THREADSTACK_SIZE` below `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN` (16384).

Comment: should ` pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREADSTACK);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);` be inside the `for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ )` loop? or is it ok where is it, outside?

Comment: It is ok to put it outside of the loop but you should linked the `pthread_attr_t` in your `pthread_create` function i.e. `pthread_create(&temp_thread, &attrs, &thread_test, (void *)&struct1);`

Comment: i understand, if so, why i cannot create more than 300 threads? I already reduced THREADSTACK, if i used `fork()` i could open more than 500 forks ... makes no sense ... what i must do to open many threads???

Comment: I test your program, I reach the 300 threads before it enters your THREAD_POOL condition, maybe you could test the program on the answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387828/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-threads-that-pthread-create-can-create), it will give you the maximum number of threads possible on your platform

Comment: BTW to compile your program I needed to add `#include <unistd.h>` for sleep functions and `using namespace std` to use string

Comment: Right now it is opening over 750 threads, i changed `rc = pthread_create(&temp_thread, NULL, &thread_test, (void *)&struct1);` to `rc = pthread_create(&temp_thread, &attrs, &thread_test, (void *)&struct1);` and also i have added `pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrs, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);` that is creating threads detached. You can try it. Now i have another problem, it is making memory leak. Here is the stackoverflow link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875814/memory-leak-in-c-threads-used-valgrind-to-debug

Comment: also i have accepted your post as the answer because you really helped me, thanks a lot