# Does C provide an API to programatically get the maximum possible number of concurrent threads on a system?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, cthreads

In C++, the standard library provides the `unsigned int std::thread::hardware_concurrency();` function as a platform-independent way to get the number of available concurrent threads at runtime.

In Golang, the same information is provided by the `GOMAXPROCS` environment variable which is provided by the runtime.

Does C (including standard and common multithreading libraries, like `pthreads`) have any such high-level API for getting the number of concurrent threads in a platform-independent way, or is it required to parse system information files to get that kind of information?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387436 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387828/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-threads-that-pthread-create-can-create.

Comment: Are you after the maximum *possible* number of threads ("*get the maximum possible number of threads*") , or the number of currently running  threads (for a process? all processes?)?

Comment: @alk I'm trying to figure out the maximum number of threads so that I can adjust how many are spawned accordingly.

Comment: @RastaJedi one of those is unanswered, and the other isn't really related to what I'm asking about. Thanks for the resources though!

Comment: One was marked as a dupe of the other, so I decided to include both. I didn't mark yours as a dupe, I just wanted to post it since it's what I found when I searched max number of threads. (The unanswered one I posted because of the `cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`, I thought maybe that was useful to you and also that he's trying to figure out max threads per process, since that might be something you are also interested in).

Comment: Go has much different threading model and GOMAXPROCS is only a promise, that go does not start more this number of system threads. It is not limit, how much threads can run. In C/C++ is up to you, how much threads you will start.

Comment: @lofcek I'm well aware; I'm just using it as an example of this kind of data being exposed to the developer.

Answer (score 2):

> Does C provide an API to programatically get the maximum possible number of threads on a system?

No.

> ... is it required to parse system information files to get that kind of information?

Yes, under Linux at least `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` contains the number you are after.

Answer (score -3):

Native C programming language does not have a threading model, but you could use a library like OpenMP or pthreads or Linux functions.

OpenMP has:

```
int omp_get_num_procs();
```

pthreads has:

```
int pthread_num_processors(); or int pthread_num_processors_np();
```

If you are using Linux you can find the number of cores:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

You could filter it with grep:

```
$ grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

Or you could use get_nprocs:

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
int get_nprocs(void);
```

Comment: "*Native C programming language does not have a threading model ...*" no, C11 has.

Comment: C11 thread's doc's are here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/4432/threads-native#t=201608131810495214013

Comment: ... and the C11 Standard (draft) on those is here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.26